# Configure Jenkins to Listen to JIRA

Tags: jenkins, jira

I have added a Jenkins WebHook to my JIRA and now I need to configure Jenkins to Listen to events sent by that WebHook.

Could you guide me a bit please, or provide a link to some support page?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track to use Jenkins WebHooks with JIRA, you could find more details on this [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-architecture/webhooks).

You could also take a look at the following resource for some additional read [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API). A sample implementation that you could refer in this area, is [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jira-trigger-plugin)

Hope this helps!